# Using malloc inside a function and return local pointer

Tags: c, return, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is there any problem in doing something like this in C

```
char* wrap(char *inp) {
    char *newstr;
    newstr = (char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * 4);
    newstr[0] = 'A';
    newstr[1] = inp[0];
    newstr[2] = 'B';
    newstr[3] = '\0';
    return newstr;
}
```

Basically I want to know that is there problem in using malloc inside a function and returning local variable.

Comment: Nope. Just be sure that someone else calls `free()`.

Comment: When designing new code that uses dynamic memory, I always have the caller send the dynamic memory allocation, rather than doing it in the sub routine.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you have to make sure that the calls to `malloc` and `free` are in the same DLL. MS run time libraries don't like memory allocated in one DLL to be freed in another DLL.

Comment: `char *newstr = malloc(4 * sizeof *newstr);`

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning a local variable; you're returning the *value* stored in a local variable.

This code is fine (although the cast on `malloc` is unnecessary); it's a somewhat common pattern to allocate memory in one function and free it in another.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfect, **as long as you're super sure the caller is going to call free** to avoid memory leaks .. That's not a big issue on small programs, but when the program gets complex, believe me, you'll be concerned about *much* more things than freeing a pointer from a supposed-to-be self-contained function ..

But (hands down), there's a much more satisfying solution to this that the standard C Library itself uses. Use a Buffer ! (Claps, Claps)

You know, there is a reason the fgets function for example requires you to provide a character pointer as the first argument, so that it can write to it rather than returning a malloc'd pointer ..

For example ..

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void toLower(char *buf, const char *s) {
    for(int i = 0; s[i]; ++i)
        buf[i] = tolower(s[i]);
}
int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
    const char *s = "ThAt'S a BiG sTrIng";
    char lower_version[strlen(s)];
    toLower(lower_version, s);
    printf("Original Version: %s\nLower Version: %s\n\tTada !\n", s, lower_version);
}
```

That way, you don't have to worry how you're going to handle the variable in later uses ..

You're leaving this problem to the function caller to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine as long as you call `free()` somewhere to avoid memory leaks. Part of your program design should be defining the "owner" of each pointer. Such ownership can be transferred, so you should keep track of the owner throughout the lifetime of the pointer. The owner at the time the pointer becomes unused should be responsible for calling `free()`.